# Creating two relationships from the same controller method in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to allow users to post pictures and comment on pictures. The pictures are related to the users through a one to many relationship and the comments are related to the pictures through a one to many relationship. I am now trying to simultaneously relate both users and pictures to comments whenever a comment is made. Currently, I am able to relate comments to either the picture or the user but not both.

Below is the controller method which handles comment uploads:

```
public function postComment(Request $request, $picture_id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        "comment" => ['required', 'max:1000'],
    ]);

    $picture = Picture::find($picture_id);

    $picture->status()->create([
        'body' => $request->input('comment'), 
    ]);

    Auth::user()->statuses()->update([
        'body' => $request->input('comment'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

I have tried creating one relationship and then creating the other relationship using update(). This did not work and resulted in the value remaining null.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Statuses is in part of my user model

Comment: public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Status', 'user_id');
    }

Comment: And status is part of my picture model:                                                                                                                                                     public function status() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Status', 'picture_id');
    }

Comment: I tried the code you suggested; however, the user_id field is still null.

Comment: Can you tell me what `dd(Auth::id())` returns? also have you added `'user_id`' to your $fillable property in your `Status` Class (or remove from the `$guarded` array)?

Comment: Thank you for your help Helioarch, adding 'user_id' to the $fillable property in my status model fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding your database model correctly, when creating the status model for your picture all you need to do is to also include the user id like so:

```
public function postComment(Request $request, $picture_id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        "comment" => ['required', 'max:1000'],
    ]);

    $picture = Picture::find($picture_id);

    $picture->status()->create([
        'body' => $request->input('comment'), 
        'user_id' => Auth::id()
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Also make sure to add user_id to the $fillable property in the `Status` model to allow it to be assigned through the create method

```
protected $fillable = [
    'body', 'user_id',
  ];
```

This should link the status you just created to both the picture and user class. You can then retrieve it elsewhere with something like `Auth::user()->statuses`